# how to call a previous item(s) in json? like xml's &lable; notation

Tags: xml, json, syntax, yaml, dry

Example in XML:

```
<"someLable">the value within that lable</"someLable">
....
<"relativeLable">&someLable;</"relativeLable">
```

Example in YAML:

```
config: &defaults
  database: "myBD"
    address: locatlhost

developement: 
  <<*defaults
```

and in JSON [I have no clue]:

```
{listOfPeople":{
    {"parent1":{"name":"value1","otherName":"otherValue1"},
    {"parent2":{"name":listOfPeople.parent2.name,"otherName":"otherValue1"}
};
```

What would I put in for listOfPeople.parent1.name
I've tried wrapping all these versions, but can't find the right one, or even if it exists in json:

- eval(I'tried self.parent2.name)
- self.parent1.name
- this.parent1.name
- parent1.name
- &parent.name;
- "&parent.name";
- &"parent"."name";
- "&parent;"."&name;"
- and various other iterations of the previous

Please clear this up for me, and if possible to post a reference for these types of reserved functions in JSON

Here is a use in the rdf:RDF definition

```
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [

<!ENTITY location "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY dc "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" >
<!ENTITY grddl "http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" >
<!ENTITY owl "&location;#" >

]>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your "XML" example is, but it isn't well-formed XML.

Comment: its not about the format of the xml/yml/or even the json

It's regarding the use of such instance variables like what is done here:


    <!ENTITY location "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" > 
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
     ....
    <!ENTITY grddl "http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" >
    <!ENTITY owl "&location;#" >

Comment: You're asking for the JSON equivalent of an "XML feature" that isn't an XML feature, so it's hard to know what you are asking for.

Comment: is that a more clear, in the entity definition the owl call is calling the location call

Comment: Yes, that is more clear.  Those are entity definitions that are made in the DTD referenced by the XML.

Comment: exactly that is what I'm looking for in JSON, 
what in json does the equivalent to "&lable;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON has no way to automatically refer to previous values.  You could add a notation to your own JSON structures, and then write your own code to interpret that notation in your decoded JSON.

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find a reference to it, any where in the documentation. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not support this.
Sorry.